# jQuery Draggable with dynamically constructed selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my current markup, there's one single `<div>` that serves as container for items preview and I would like to make it draggable using jQuery UI.

Following the basics from the tutorial, since I never did such a thing, it would be just a matter of:

```
$( '#preview' ).draggable();
```

And, in fact, it was. I added it and it worked.

However I need a slightly more specific selector, so other things sharing the same preview container don't become draggable as well.

So while building the previewing I added a `class` to identify the group, i.e:

```
$( '#preview' ).removeClass().addClass( 'group_1' );
```

And then I did the same to the other preview triggers with different strings (i.e. group_2, group_3...)

Inspecting the preview element in Chrome it's working perfectly as it should: all classes are removed from the element and the new one is added.

Thinking that was all I needed, I then changed the jQuery UI Selector to:

```
$( '#preview.group_1' ).draggable();
```

And it stopped working.

Is there something specific I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided much of an example. So it's hard to know if this is what you're looking for. Try:

```
$("#preview[class^='group_']").draggable();
```

This will apply draggable to the ID of `preview` and class like `group_1, group_2, group_n`. See more: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Again, with no example code, it's hard to know what elements this will catch. IDs should be unique. For example, you mentioned only one `<div>` being used:

```
<div id="preview" class="group_1">
</div>
```

So it's not clear why you're changing the class.

You mention you have other elements that share this parent should not be draggable. For example:

```
<div id="preview">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="image_thumb.job">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
    </div>
</div>
```

When you call `$("#preview").draggable()`, This will make the container draggable, not the items within; unless, you have set 'preview' as the ID for other elements, which is not advised.

**Update**

Consider an alternative to removing all classes.

`$("#preview").removeClass("group_1").addClass("group_2");`

This would prevent the `ui-draggable` from being removed. You can also be more in-depth with your seeking:

```
$("#preview").removeClass(function(i, c) {
  if (c.indexOf("group_") !== -1) {
    var res = c.split(" ");
    $.each(res, function(k, v){
      if(v.indexOf("group_") === 0){
        return v;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This will remove just one class that starts with `group_` or it could be adjusted to fit other cases. Or remove all but:

```
$("#preview").removeClass(function(i, c) {
  if (c.indexOf("ui-draggable") >= 0) {
    var res = c.split(" ");
    $.each(res, function(k, v){
      if(v.indexOf("ui-draggable") === -1){
        return v;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This would remove all classes except for `ui-draggable`. You can also use the index, `i`, to only look at specific elements in a larger number of elements. Hope that helps.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but apparently the code was written correctly but, even though I was seeing in the Inspector that the element `#preview` was losing and receiving the different group classes correctly, apparently the `draggable()` method wasn't... "watching" for these changes. So, Instead of trigger all routines, wrapped in a function (including the call to `draggable()`) in the beginning of code, I called it right after adding theses classes to the element and it worked.

Comment: This makes sense. When dialog is initiated it adds classes: `ui-dialog` when you remove them all, you have to initialize dialog again.

Comment: I'll test tomorrow and reverting the moment I initialize the draggable back to where it was and working as intended, I'll mark as solved.